# Get form data using python

Tags: python, cgi

How do i get form data in my Python code. Below is my current code.

```
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import cgi
import sys

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = form.getValue('name')
print 'Hello ' + name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = form['name'].value
print 'Hello ' + name
```

Comment: May I know what should i do to make this work in Google App Engine? Thanks!