# CGI with Python

Tags: python, cgi

I'm beginning to use CGI with Python.

After running the following piece of code:

```
#!c:\python34\python.exe

import cgi


print("Content-type: text/html\n\n") #important


def getData():
    formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
    InputUN = formData.getvalue('username')
    InputPC = formData.getvalue('passcode')
    TF = open("TempFile.txt", "w")
    TF.write(InputUN)
    TF.write(InputPC)
    TF.close()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    LoginInput = getData()
    print("cgi worked")
```

The following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\actual\loginvalues.cgi", line 21, in <module>
    LoginInput = getData()
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\actual\loginvalues.cgi", line 16, in getData
    TF.write(InputUN)
TypeError: must be str, not None
>>>
```

I'm trying to write the values, inputted in html, to a text file.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891245/get-form-data-using-python ?

Comment: Yes but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Your calls to `getValue()` are returning `None`, meaning the form either didn't contain them, had them set to an empty string, or had them set by name only. Python's CGI module ignores inputs that aren't set to a non-null string.

Works for Python CGI:

- `mysite.com/loginvalues.cgi?username=myname&pass=mypass`

Doesn't work for Python CGI:

- `mysite.com/loginvalues.cgi?username=&pass=` (null value(s))
- `mysite.com/loginvalues.cgi?username&pass` (Python requires the `=` part.)

To account for this, introduce a default value for when a form element is missing, or handle the None case manually:

```
TF.write('anonymous' if InputUN is None else InputUN)
TF.write('password' if InputPC is None else InputUN)
```

As a note, passwords and other private login credentials should never be used in a URL. **URLs are not encrypted**. Even in HTTPS, the URL is sent in plain text that anyone on the network(s) between you and your users can read.

The only time a URL is ever encrypted is over a tunneled SSH port or an encrypted VPN, but you can't control that, so never bank on it.